# PHP: working with checkboxes

Tags: php

I have a form, and inside it there's a while() with checkboxes.

I wish to have so when you mark and then press submit, the message will remove.

Now, I have the checkboxes, and the submit button and so. Now all my checkboxes are like this:

```
   <input class="cbPick" name="cbPick" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

How can i work with that in PHP? Should i do, $_POST["cbPick"] to know if its marked or not ?

And when i have more with these, how can i know which is which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check boxes require the use of an array. PHP will automatically place the checked boxes into an array if you place [] brackets at the end of each name.

```
Please choose type of food:<br />
Steak:<input type="checkbox" value="Steak" name="food[]">:<br />
Pizza:<input type="checkbox" value="Pizza" name="food[]">:<br />
Chicken:<input type="checkbox" value="Chicken" name="food[]">:<br />
```

Then you can do

```
$foodArray=$_POST['food'];
echo $foodArray[0]; //Steak Value
echo $foodArray[1]; //Pizza Value
echo $foodArray[2]; //Chicken Value
```

PS - This information was found by Googling "[Checkboxes PHP](http://www.google.com/search?q=checkboxes+php)" and clicking the first link. I encourage you to do at least a little research in the future before posting a question that has anwers so readily available.

Comment: That is assuming the checkboxes are being used for selecting things from a list. In some cases however, such as an "I Agree" checkbox for a terms & conditions page, this is not needed.

Comment: The OP stated that there are checkboxes create by a loop. I think it goes without saying this is not such a case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_POST['cbPick']])) {
  // Do stuff here
}
```

empty() checks first for existence, then if the value is non-nullish (null, zero, empty string, etc). That way you won't get a notice if the array key doesn't exist. Checkboxes are a little weird in that they only come through in the $_POST array if they are checked. Otherwise the variable is not posted at all.

Comment: Ok, and when i have something in the value="" how can i ouput that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same name (`cbPick[]`) for a few checkboxes, `$_POST["cbPick"]` will be filled as an array with each of the checked values.